# Cordova inAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, webview, window.open, inappbrowser

I'm using cordova inAppBrowser and loading webview from server but inside my server code(javascript) there is another window.open for showing reports (PDF) which is not opening in my app. How to make it open. I'm unable to use app cordova in server code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you just share your code. So that I can try to help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override window.open with cordova in appBrowser method on device ready event as they mentioned in documenation.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
}
```